# How can I animate my collection view cells smaller while editing?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So I have a collection view which lays out cells 2 per row. When I go into editing mode I would like for the cells to reduce in size all around. I tried adding padding to them to get the desired effect which works but I need them to animate in! How could I accomplish this. Please see my code bellow:

Initial set up when view loads:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
    navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true

    // Does not allow to move items around innitialy
    installsStandardGestureForInteractiveMovement = false

    // set collectionView item size
    //let width = collectionView!.frame.width/2
    let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let itemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2.0
    let paddingSpace: CGFloat = 2.0 * itemsPerRow
    let availableWidth = view.frame.width - paddingSpace
    let widthPerItem = availableWidth / itemsPerRow
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 4.0
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem)

}
```

Then this is what gets called when "edit" is tapped

```
func reduceCellSize() {

    if isEditing {
        let layout = self.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout

        let itemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2.0
        let paddingSpace: CGFloat = 8.0 * itemsPerRow
        let availableWidth = self.view.frame.width - paddingSpace
        let widthPerItem = availableWidth / itemsPerRow
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 6.0
        layout.sectionInset.left = 5
        layout.sectionInset.right = 5
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem)
    } else {
        let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let itemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2.0
        let paddingSpace: CGFloat = 2.0 * itemsPerRow
        let availableWidth = view.frame.width - paddingSpace
        let widthPerItem = availableWidth / itemsPerRow
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 4.0
        layout.sectionInset.left = 0
        layout.sectionInset.right = 0
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is `CGAffineTransform`. So you can set their overall size like this:

```
    private func transformCell() {
            var offset : Float = 0.0

            for cell in numberCollectionView.visibleCells as! [MyCell] {


                offset = 0.07
                cell.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: CGFloat(offset), y: CGFloat(offset))

            }
     }
```

It will transform the visible cells into different size according to offset value and you can call it from `scrollViewDidScroll`

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {


            transformCell()

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! So this works but I also need the cells to animate when I tap "edit" and also to animate back to normal when I tap "done". Any suggestions for that? Thanks!

Comment: implement scrolltoitem on your edit and done tap and it will call scrollViewDidScroll

Comment: Also when I added the `UIViewAnimation` to the block of code you provided, when I scrolled down the collection view, every new cell is animated which isn't the desired effect - all new cells should just be the same size as what the other cells were animated to

Comment: in mycode it says visibleCells. If you want to animate all of them you don't need the numberCollectionView.visibleCells rather all cells

Comment: beside i believe tweaking my code is your solution :)

Comment: This was a great help to me and I was able to figure the rest out! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Glad that it helped :)

Comment: One last thing! =] if I moveItemAt index the cells go back to their original sizes. Is there a way to prevent that until I tap "done"? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the end of your reduceCellSize method:

```
UIView.animate(duration: 0.3) {
  self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

(Where you replace "collectionView" with the actual name of your collection view.)

That should cause the collection view to animate the resizing Of its subviews.

Comment: Thanks for helping but there seems to be a "white flash" on the cell when doing this. It is animating though

Comment: Hello Ducan! I am new to Swift and don't understand quite what you mean when you said: `Where you replace "collectionView" with the actual name of your collection view.` - could you clarify?

Comment: If it compiles then you don't have to do anything